# Not able to open Excel File which contain Graph

Tags: python, email, smtp, email-attachments

**Edit question for new issue**
 I was able to get Email But it was delay from server side.**

I am writing very small application for sending email with attachment of excel file in python. it contain multiple worksheet and each worksheet contain graph. I received email but it looks like File was corrupted.
is it possible to attach Excel which contain graph( size also upto 2MB)

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from smtplib import SMTP
import smtplib,email,email.encoders,email.mime.text,email.mime.base

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Email From Python Abhishek'
msg['From'] = 'xyz.com'
msg['To'] = 'abc.com'

fileMsg = email.mime.base.MIMEBase('application','vnd.ms-excel')
fileMsg.set_payload(file('Final.xlsx').read())
email.encoders.encode_base64(fileMsg)
fileMsg.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename=Final.xlsx')
msg.attach(fileMsg)

smtp = SMTP("email exchange server",25) 
#(I was able to connect with exchange server using Telnet http://www.exchangeinbox.com/article.aspx?i=93)


# Start the server:
smtp.ehlo()

I have commented below code as per one internet posting. it suggest that if you
are sending internal Email you may not require login and password.I also do not
want to write password as it is violate company policy
if I  remove comment from line. it give me error for bad authentication.
#smtp.login("abc", "password")

smtp.sendmail(msg['From'],msg['To'],msg.as_string())
#server.quit()
```

Comment: Check your mails server logs

Comment: Correct I got mail but it was very Delay.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that I have used for sending email from a gmail account, it should work for others in theory, but I have only tested with gmail. You can call it from the command line passing in the arguements listed in main or you can call the mail function directly from another Python module:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# currently set up and tested on gmail only

import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email import Encoders
import os, sys, base64

def mail(gmail_user, enc_pwd, to, subject, body, attach):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    msg['From'] = gmail_user
    msg['To'] = to
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))

    if attach:
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(open(attach, 'rb').read())
        Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
               'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(attach))
        msg.attach(part)

    mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.starttls()
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.login(gmail_user, base64.b64decode(enc_pwd))
    mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
    mailServer.close()

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) <6:
        print "Usage: send_email.py <from> <enc_pwd> <to> <subject> <body> " \
              "[<attachments>]"
        print "Note: Email is being sent in html mode, so any newlines should " \
              "be sent as <br/>"
        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            print "\nThe following arguements were received:"
            for i in sys.argv:
                print i
    else:
        gmail_user  = sys.argv[1]
        gmail_pwd   = sys.argv[2]
        to          = sys.argv[3]
        subject     = sys.argv[4]
        body        = sys.argv[5]
        attach      = None
        if len(sys.argv) >= 7:
            attach  = sys.argv[6]

        mail(gmail_user, gmail_pwd, to, subject, body, attach)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Thanks for reply but I have two query. 1) why Email server takes so much time.  2) what is wrong with my code I am able to send attchment but not able to open file

Comment: @AbhishekGoswami before I look in detail to see if I can spot any issues with your code, can you confirm whether you can open the attachment when it is sent using the code above?

Comment: I am not able to open excel attachment. I tried multiple time but never work

Comment: Thanks for your code. I compare code with the code you have provided and found that I did not read the file. "fileMsg.set_payload(file('Final.xlsx', 'rb').read())